# Brace initialization of Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, list-initialization

Using gcc 9.4.0 and Eigen 3.3.7, the following compiles without issue:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main(int Argc, char *Argv[]) {
    Eigen::Matrix<int, 1, 4> d = {1, 2, 3, 4};
}
```

Increasing the length by 1 provokes an error:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main(int Argc, char *Argv[]) {
    Eigen::Matrix<int, 1, 5> d = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    }

foo.cpp:6:48: error: could not convert ‘{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Eigen::Matrix<int, 1, 5>’
    6 |     Eigen::Matrix<int, 1, 5> d = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
      |                                                ^
      |                                                |
      |                                                <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```

The second case is a copy of a line from the Eigen tutorial page.

Can someone explain the problem with the 2nd case?

**UPDATE: Based on comments below, this appears to be a bug in the Eigen library. I've submitted a bug report.**

**UPDATE UPDATE: Per answer below, Eigen 3.3 specifically allows brace initializers up to 4 parameters, while Eigen 3.4 allows general brace initialization. The Mint distro version is 3.3 (a year after 3.4 released!) while the Eigen documentation now refers to the 3.4 version.**

Comment: The program compiles fine when i tried it on my pc.

Comment: I can reproduce using the specified EIgen and compiler versions https://godbolt.org/z/YY41Pfzev I would go ahead and file an issue on their GitLab page gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen

Comment: Looks like bug in Eigen which is fixed in 3.4: https://godbolt.org/z/v1dnG8qKz

Answer (score 5):

Brace initialization is not supported by Eigen 3.3.x. If you write

```
Eigen::Matrix<int, 1, 4> d = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

It will call the `Eigen::Matrix(S const& x, S const& y, S const& z, S const& w)` constructor [link](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.3/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html#a1b56bac44d4b7d0d652f03daf6d99dca). Eigen has constructors for up to 4 elements, which only work for vector-like matrices which have the correct number of elements at compile-time.

Initializer lists work with Eigen 3.4.x if C++11 or later is enabled: [link](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html#title3).

Comment: link/quote to respective documentation would make this answer much better.

Comment: @MarekR I added links, these are not guaranteed to work forever, though.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain the problem with the 2nd case?

Technically there is nothing wrong with the 2nd case.

This seems to be a eigen library's bug that **only happens when you use** `C++11` with gcc 9.4 and eigen trunk.

The **error goes away if you change the standard to** `C++14` or higher.

See [working demo with c++14](https://godbolt.org/z/qEGs8PYdb) with gcc 9.4 and eigen trunk.

---

On the other hand the problem remains irrespective of the standard c++ version you use with eigen 3.3.7.  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vKEnrbvdY). I've tried different combinations of standard version with compiler versions and eigen library version and they seem to give inconsistent result. So, this is a bug in the library(eigen) and there is nothing wrong from your side.

Comment: Eigen trunk requires C++14 or later. Eigen 3.4 is the last version which is compatible with C++03/C++11 (compiling with C++11 enables some additional functionality, such as move construction/assignment).

Comment: Use Eigen 3.3.7 to reproduce issue and 3.4.0 to see it is fixed: https://godbolt.org/z/v1dnG8qKz